# Spark connects to database every time I perform a Transformation/Action?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running Spark 2.1.0 on Windows 10. I connected to a MySQL database to get data into spark using JDBC. As shown below, whenever I perform an action I get the following warning which makes me wonder that the data is being retrieved from database for every operation.

```
scala> val jdbcDF2 = spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
Wed Mar 29 15:05:23 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
jdbcDF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, site: bigint ... 15 more fields]

scala> jdbcDF2.count
Wed Mar 29 15:09:09 IST 2017 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
```

If this is the case, is there a way by which I can save the data in a spark local object like a DataFrame so that it doesn't have to connect to database all the time?

I tried to [cache the table](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#caching-data-in-memory) and it runs successfully but I am unable to use Spark-SQL on the table

```
scala> jdbcDF2.cache()
res6: jdbcDF2.type = [id: bigint, site: bigint ... 15 more fields]
scala> val unique = sql("SELECT DISTINCT site FROM jdbcDF2")
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: jdbcDF2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your queries after caching directly on your DataFrame using

`val unique = jdbcDF2.selectExpr("count(distinct site)")`

or

`val unique = jdbcDF2.select("site").distinct.count`

or
creating a temporary view from your DataFrame and access it via sqlContext

```
jdbcDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("jdbcDF2")
val unique = sql("SELECT DISTINCT site FROM jdbcDF2")
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right to cache your DataFrame for later reuse and in order not to query your database at each Spark action (collect, count, first, ...)

But to use SQL to query your DataFrame, first you have to do :

```
jdbcDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
```

and then :

```
sql("SELECT DISTINCT site FROM my_table")
```